# Will the Japanese version RWBY remake the animation or just be changing the voice actors and actresses?

Tags: anime-production, rwby

I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUTUMlAdfmM) and read [on the news](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/interest/2014-08-15/rooster-teeth-rwby-heads-to-japan/.77670) that RWBY was going to be dubbed by Japanese. I was wondering if the Japanese version would remake the animation, like anime style, or use the original animation, just replacing the voice actors and actresses. Does anyone know an article or a thread regarding this matter?

Comment: Reading the article, since it just said dubbed, i doubt they will be touching anything regarding the animation. Dubbed usually means they just swap out the voice acting. There has been cases where "sensitive" subjects that the ATF frowns upon gets swapped out during localization, though. Even in that case, its censoring, rather than wholesale remakes. If anything to that extent was going to happen, I'm sure they'd mention it.

Comment: Sorry for that. I forgot to change it. Anyway, so the entire volume will be redubbed in Japanese, having two different versions?

Comment: Your first link is to an [unofficial Japanese dub project](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSH7ruLqwsMHbUUg0WEYI6N1DZRMlhUSs). It's more likely this would be a localization (same content, different voices) than a new release... but who knows? Given that this is a BD release it's possible that there would be some touch up here and there for HD.

Answer (score 3):

I have compared the animation and dialogue in the English and Japanese versions of the first episode of RWBY ("Ruby Rose"). The dialogue and voices have been set to match the flaps of the character's mouths rather than the other way round.

The dub is purely audio, no animation changes were made. This is typical of most localisation dubs both in the western world and in Japan also.